# `mount -o loop` changes mounted ISO image file

Tags: mount, iso, checksum

It looks like `mount -o loop` changes the mounted image file. I downloaded the ISO image file and checked its SHA-1 checksum. Then I mounted that ISO file and the checksum changed. Here are the exact steps I made, a copy-paste from my console, CentOS 7 x64 (note, that ISO file is read-only):

```
[mbartnicki@89-78-33-81 Downloads]$ ls -lh
total 3.1G
-r--r--r--. 1 mbartnicki mbartnicki 3.1G Mar 31 18:28 X17-58997.iso
[mbartnicki@89-78-33-81 Downloads]$ sha1sum X17-58997.iso 
6c9058389c1e2e5122b7c933275f963edf1c07b9  X17-58997.iso
[mbartnicki@89-78-33-81 Downloads]$ sudo mount -o loop X17-58997.iso /mnt/iso/
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
[mbartnicki@89-78-33-81 Downloads]$ sha1sum X17-58997.iso 
994944df320e9e03c032263d7b9e36157a0a587c  X17-58997.iso
```

I was so surprised, that I repeated above steps on another machine (Ubuntu 14.04 x64), just to get the same result: file checksum changed after `mount -o loop`. Unmounting ISO image doesn't return its checksum to original value; file change is persistent. Moreover, next mount change the checksum again to some new value. How can it be explained?

**PS**

Mounting explicitly read-only by adding `ro` mount option prevents file from being changed, so that if I use:

`sudo mount -o ro,loop X17-58997.iso /mnt/iso`

then everything is OK, and ISO image file lasts unchanged after mount. The wrong behaviour occurs only when `ro` option is not specified, even if the ISO image file is read-only on the file system level. I tried on three different ISO images: Windows 7 installation DVD (official), SystemRescueCD (small rescue Linux) and hand-made ISO created by `genisoimage` tool.

I checked all that ISO files with `file` utility, and `file` said that all of them are *ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data*. Files inside ISO images are not changed - I also checked it - it looks like the faulty mount scenario adds some meta-data or just garbage.

Comment: What is the sha1sum after unmounting?

Comment: Can you try with an empty iso image, created by `genisoimage -o empty.iso emptydir`?

Comment: can you try making new loop device and try to mount the `iso` to it? You can use `mknod -m 660 /dev/loop1 b 7 1` also after run `chmod 660 /dev/loop*`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel unmounting doesn't return previous checksum. File is changed for good. But thanks for pointing this out, I 'm going to edit my question to include this information.

Comment: All really strange... Does mounting it again change it again?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel yes, I also noted it in my edit.

Comment: Because it looks like a bug - anything relevant in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kern.log`? Can you try other iso files?

Comment: Similar bug report at launchpad: [mount -o loop.... changes the udf image](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kernel-package/+bug/1277146)

Comment: I added a link to this question to the launchpad bug.

Comment: QUESTION: What happens if you EXPLICITLY mount the ISO as read-only using the 'ro' option parameter on the mount command?

Comment: @goldilocks I see... so I'll post this solution to the bug report I linked. To me, part of the confusion is from the expectation that an iso image should behave the same like a CD - not change.

Comment: It does not apply to the iso9660 Linux driver, but it's interesting to note that some lower level modifications are still possible in other cases. See the [--read only](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#COMMAND_LINE%20OPTIONS) option in the manpages.

Answer (score 1):

Iso isn't synonym for read only, under some circunstances, you may wish to mount an iso read/write (when creating a boot media).

If you want read only, use option

```
 mount -o ro,iso
```

Comment: My ISO file was read-only by file system permissions, and it was mounted read-only as stated in the mount output.